# Send and Receive data Simultaneously via Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a little game that sends location data between a client an server to learn how Sockets work.

The server can send and receive data no problem, and the client can send data, but when the client tries to read in data from the server, the program hangs. (This part is commented out)

Server Code:

```
public void run() {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10007);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 10007.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Connection successful");
    System.out.println("Waiting for input.....");
    while (true) {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            if (in.readLine() != "0" && in.readLine() != null) {
                setXY(in.readLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        out.println("X" + Graphics.charX);
        out.println("Y" + Graphics.charY);
    }
```

Client Code:

```
public void run() {

    try {
        System.out.println("Attemping to connect to host " + serverHostname + " on port " + serverPort + ".");
        echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, serverPort);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverHostname);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for " + "the connection to: " + serverHostname);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    while (true) {

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            /*if (in.readLine() != "0" && in.readLine() != null) {
                setXY(in.readLine());
            }*/
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.println("X" + Graphics.charX);
        out.println("Y" + Graphics.charY);

    }

}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing any threading here?

Comment: Yes, this class is one thread.

Comment: Well, you're not threading correctly, not at all, and you will want to look into how to do this with threads. This sort of question has been asked quite a bit, so do a bit of searching -- it will be rewarding for you if you do.

Comment: Thank you. The threading was absolutely the problem. I'm re-writing it to split it into 2 threads: read & write. The problem is that the thread is getting hung when it calls in.readLine(), so it needs to be split into two threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two threads to read/write blocking sockets at the same time (which is what you're trying to do). When you call `in.readLine()`, the current thread will block until it receives a line of data.